# After returning from using dismissViewControllerAnimated, clicking any other button crash app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I Have 2 views. View1 and view 2.

I am opening view 2 from view 1 by using

```
view2 *store2 = [[view2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"view2" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self presentViewController:store2 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then I have added a button on view2 to to dismiss view2 and return to view1 with the code:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

The dismiss works well and  get back to view1. But each time when I click on any button or any part on view1 after I return there, app crashes.

Kindly guide to go through this. I used this code in past projects and it always worked.

Comment: Can you show the code you init and present view1?

Comment: Can you say what is the error message you are getting while crash?

Comment: I think you are presenting a view rather than VC and dismissing VC itself. try removeFromSubView

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like no other object is retaining view1's view controller. The view is presented properly since it doesn't need to be retained by anybody in order to be displayed, however, once you try to interact with it, it need its view controller to be alive and responsive. My guess is that if you have view1's view controller as another object's property, or hold it in any other way as long as its view is displayed, you'll be able to use view1's buttons without crashing the app.